# Air 3.3 - screen size on the new Ipad

Tags: flash, apache-flex, air, retina-display

I recently upgraded the air version I use to 3.3 , that caused an issue on the new ipad - all the content is now 1/4 of the screen size.

Any Ideas on how to resolve this ?

Thanks

Comment: Are you using a Mac and have you specified the latest version of the iOS SDK?  this should be in your project properties under the ANE setting.  Are you specifying an ApplicationDPI value?

Comment: I am using a mac, I did not specify the latest version of ios sdk nor applicationdpi value, where can I find documentation on that ?  Thanks

Comment: No idea; but the current version of Flex/AIR is not aware of the new iPad screen resolution because of the bundled iOS SDK.  You can specify a different iOS SDK; but the workflow is only currently available on a Mac.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the workaround for the retina display here: http://www.overdigital.com/2012/05/08/the-new-retina-ipad-and-adobe-air/

With Air 3.4 that should be done automatically, though. Can't wait for the final release.

Comment: air 3.4 is out , did not check yet if solves issue , will update once i check it

Comment: Please do that. I too haven't had the time to test it yet, so let us know.